# Suppressing FXCOP error for vb.net Method

Tags: vb.net, code-analysis, suppress-warnings, fxcop-customrules, vb.net-module

I want to suppress FXCOP error(CA1811) for specific vb.net function.
Like `<SuppressMessage()>` in c#, do we alternative of this in VB.net?

I am new to vb.net.

Comment: Is this false positive ?
Its good practice to solve it always.

Comment: Yes its False Positive :)

Answer (score 0):

FXCop analyzes the compiled assemblies, i.e., it doesn't care whether the assembly was written in C# or VB.NET.

Thus, the same technique that works in C# should also work in VB.NET. Note that, in VB.NET, the syntax for adding attributes is `[SuppressMessage(...)]` rather than C#'s `<SuppressMessage(...)>`.

Comment: I tried this,  Still when I run standalone FXCOP, I am getting same  FXCOP error(CA1811)